# Restlet Version 2.2 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.newFactory()

Tags: java, restlet

I am using the Restlet Version 2.2.0 with the IBM jdk 1.6.0_26 and I am trying to implement a REST Service. While executing my test project I am getting the following error:

```
Starting the internal [HTTP/1.1] server on port 8080
Server started ...
An exception occured writing the response entity

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.newFactory()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;
    at org.restlet.ext.jackson.JacksonRepresentation.createObjectMapper(JacksonRepresentation.java:215)
    at org.restlet.ext.jackson.JacksonRepresentation.getObjectMapper(JacksonRepresentation.java:333)
    at org.restlet.ext.jackson.JacksonRepresentation.createObjectWriter(JacksonRepresentation.java:277)
    at org.restlet.ext.jackson.JacksonRepresentation.getObjectWriter(JacksonRepresentation.java:361)
    at org.restlet.ext.jackson.JacksonRepresentation.write(JacksonRepresentation.java:474)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ServerCall.writeResponseBody(ServerCall.java:519)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ServerCall.sendResponse(ServerCall.java:463)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ServerAdapter.commit(ServerAdapter.java:196)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:153)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpServerHelper$1.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:73)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:77)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:80)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:567)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:539)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:737)
Unable to send error response

java.io.IOException: headers already sent
    at sun.net.httpserver.ExchangeImpl.sendResponseHeaders(ExchangeImpl.java:180)
    at sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchangeImpl.sendResponseHeaders(HttpExchangeImpl.java:80)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpExchangeCall.writeResponseHead(HttpExchangeCall.java:157)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ServerCall.sendResponse(ServerCall.java:459)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ServerAdapter.commit(ServerAdapter.java:214)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:153)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpServerHelper$1.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:73)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:77)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:80)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:567)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:539)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:737)
```

While using Sun/Oracle  1.6 JDK the problem doesn't exist, but I need to stay at 
IBM jdk 1.6.0_26.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
EHa

Comment: Looks like incompatible jars of restlet and javax-xml

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a problem with the fallback JAXP selection between the two JDKs. Run java with `-Djaxp.debug=1` and have a look at your logs. I'm currently encountering this same issue and my logs are showing

```
JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
JAXP: loaded from fallback value: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
JAXP: created new instance of class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl using ClassLoader: null
```

I'm pretty certain that my issue is OSGi related. Here's the link to another question with what could be a similar outcome: [Unable to find a factory for http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222413/unable-to-find-a-factory-for-http-www-w3-org-2001-xmlschema)

Comment: Did you have a solution here ? If so, can you remember which one? :)

Comment: @Victor I was able to get past it, though I can't speak with certainty regarding how. I suspect it was explicitly selecting the Thread's ContextClassLoader as I was in an OSGi environment.

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same error but in a different context. The error was sourced from the following:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
...
...
    private static XmlMapper xmlMapper=null;
...
...
    xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
```

From this [comment here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/23994#issuecomment-1111074194) I thought to change the version of of `jackson-dataformat-xml` from `2.14.2` down to `2.12.7`, and it worked.